# Источник null-listener'a. parameter specified as non-null is null

Tags: android, kotlin

Делаю пет-проект для обучения и решил добавить в него MVVM-архитектуру. После добавления вью-модели к фрагменту и ее реализации получил такую ошибку:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter listener
    at com.onopry.budgetapp.model.TransactionService.addListener(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.onopry.budgetapp.viewmodels.TransactionsViewModel.loadTransactions(TransactionsViewModel.kt:23)
    at com.onopry.budgetapp.viewmodels.TransactionsViewModel.<init>(TransactionsViewModel.kt:19)
    at com.onopry.budgetapp.viewmodels.ViewModelsFactory.create(ViewModelsFactory.kt:19)
```

В `TransactionService` есть сет слушателей данных, сам он наследуется от класса `App()` и он добавлен в манифест `android:name=".App"`

Единственное добавление слушателя `TransactionService` происходит во вью модели фрагмента. Не понимаю в чем может быть причина

TransactionService.kt

```
typealias TransactionsListener = (transactions: List<TransactionsDto>) -> Unit

class TransactionService {
private var transactionsList = mutableListOf<TransactionsDto>()
private val listeners = mutableSetOf<TransactionsListener>()

    init {
    // generate mutableList
        }

/*some methods: fun (add/get/delete/edit)Transactions{} with call notifyChanges()*/
        
fun addListener(listener: TransactionsListener){
        listeners.add(listener)
        listener.invoke(transactionsList)
}

fun removeListener(listener: TransactionsListener){ listeners.remove(listener) }

//invoke all listeners for generated list
private fun notifyChanges(){ 
    listeners.forEach { it.invoke(transactionsList) } 
}
}
```

TransactionsViewModel.kt

```
class TransactionsViewModel(
private val transactionService: TransactionService
): ViewModel() {

private val _transactions = MutableLiveData<List<TransactionsDto>>()
val transactions: LiveData<List<TransactionsDto>> = _transactions

init {
    loadTransactions()
}

fun loadTransactions(){
    transactionService.addListener(listener)
}

private val listener: TransactionsListener = { _transactions.value = it }

fun deleteTransaction(transaction: TransactionsDto){ transactionService.deleteTransaction(transaction) }
fun addTransaction(transaction: TransactionsDto){ transactionService.addTransaction(transaction) }
fun editTransaction(transaction: TransactionsDto, id: Int, newAmount:Int, newCategory: CategoriesDto){ transactionService.editTransaction(transaction, id, newAmount, newCategory) }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если переместите `private val listener` **НАД** методом `init` во ViewModel все заработает.
сначала должны идти переменные, потом `init`, и потом уже функции.

Comment: Спасибо, очень сам не понял как упустил этот момент